# How to locate an element which is visible only by mouse hover in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to find an element which is visible by mouse hover and I need to click on it and it then opens a text field. When I give the XPath for the element in fire-path, it detects 6 instances of the element. I need the first element. I'm using Java and when I try to run the script it gives me error about unable to locate the element

[image]

Comment: You could use direct mouse control either via [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com) or [Kantu](https://kantu.io/sikuli) to trigger a mouse-over effect that then triggers the DOM change.

Answer (score 1):

By definition locators should be unique, if your locator returns 6 matches it means it's not unique. 
If you want to use hover, you can either use Actions class in selenium to achieve this, or use JavaScript Executor to do a hover( Not recommended though) 
Alternatively you could change your locators to use css selector(Highly recommended) , class names etc

Comment: I routinely use locators (names, css class) which return a list of elements, and detect the one needed by some other attribute. I found this approach less flaky than XPath.

Answer (score 0):

use getattribute function in the webdriver with the Xpath then you will get that specific instance of the element

```
  Boolean b= driver.findbyelement(by.xpath("")).getattribute('transparent');
```

Check b is true or false if it true then you are select the correct instance

Or you can use the css as well

```
driver.findbyelement(by.xpath("")).getattribute('background-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath offers a way to select the Nth matching element of your expression by giving:

```
//expression[n]
```

Although this is going to select all the Nth `children` elements of matching nodes to your expression. So, it will return many results in your case also.

But there is a solution. In order to achieve a `global` selection of the Nth matching element you need to wrap your expression in parantheses:

```
(//expression)[n]
```

So, in your case it would be (note the wrapping parantheses):

```
(//i[@title='Rename' and ng-click='editCampaignName($index)'])[1]
```

Let us know if it worked for you.

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580255/3652270

Comment: Thanks for the solution you provided but unfortunately I'm unable to use the above technique to find the element. It is giving unable to locate element error

Comment: @KrishnaKishore I edited my answer. I changed the opening parenthesis to include also //. It was my mistake. Can you try again?

Comment: @KrishnaKishore Are you trying to implement above solution after hovering? try isElementVisible() checking before performing any operating to debug this scenario, I am sure you would be able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This approach is very brittle and should be generally avoided and only used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is a good idea but if you keep getting an error, try to use a JavascriptExecutor to click on the element.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//(i[@title='Rename' and ng-click='editCampaignName($index)'])[1]"));

        //in order to click a non visible element
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use Actions if u are trying to find an element in a tooltip.For example

```
Actions tooltip = new Actions(driver);
tooltip.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("The xpath that u want to move your mouse there")).build.perform();
//After this, U can then try to get the element in that tooltip
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the xpath of the element from browser

1. select the element under which this hidden element is expected to appear.
2. Right click and select Force state --> ':hover'

[image]

This will expose the element. Get its xpath.

On Selenium-webdriver use *moveToElement(<parent_element>).perform()*
and locate the required element using the xpath previously found